# how force pc client to join local specific domain controller first

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have one forest (and one Domian) Active Directory Windows 2008 R2 with 4 physical sites. Each sites have 2 DC. 
When we add a PC client to our Domain, it'going to different domain controler first. We want the PC is going to 1 local DC first.
It's possible ?

"Sites and active directory" are well set up, and the first primary DNS is a local DC.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As per joeqwerty's comment, take my first 2 sentences with a grain of salt
and consult [this document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782048%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more information

---

<strike>I don't think you have a well setup forest.</strike>

<strike>Ideally you should have  created</strike> Consider having 1 domain per physical site depending on the geographical dispersion of your sites.

A node joins a domain not a DC. You shouldn't bother with which particular DC you authenticate,etc.

Having said that, if your DC holds the GC and it's DNS has the appropriate _kerberos and _ldap SRV records , all the networking makes sense (subnets,routes and so on) , you might want to check [this thread on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/109056/how-to-force-machines-in-an-ad-site-to-authenticate-against-a-gc-in-their-own-si) as well.

Comment: Your first two sentences are truly off the mark.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thank you for your comment. Can you please clarify?

Comment: 1. You don't need a domain for every physical site. Creating a domain for every physical site would be bad design in my opinion. - 2. You should bother with which particular DC authenticates you. I don't want a domain client in London authenticating to a DC in Los Angeles.

Comment: [Microsoft seems to agree with both of us](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782048(v=ws.10).aspx) . But I agree that it depends on what you want to achieve and what's the distance between your sites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All Our DC (on each physical sites) hold the GC and DNS records as you say. We use active directory sites to optimize replication, authentication, and another services (as said in one your link). Anywhere it's said that "Sites active directory" can be used to add a PC in the Domain and force to use first a local domain controler.
Is there any way to do that for each our sites ?

Comment: Have you looked at your subnets configuration? Have a look [at this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754697.aspx) . 
Also I just found that this exact same question has been [answered before on serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/318707/force-windows-server-to-use-specific-domain-controller)